# Strange behaviour of window.backgroundColor

Tags: swift

I am trying to change the title bar color for an OSX app.. Using window!.backgroundColor = ....works sometimes but not others. Or to be more specific it works sometimes when running the app and not others, even without rebuilding between runs.  I have tried setting this in the main window controller and in several view controllers (with view.window!.background color but all give the same behaviour.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 0):

OK, fixed it, switching off textured in storyboard solved the problem..